# Issue with Join between Query in PHPmyadmin and website

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do I think a simple left join between Table A and Table B. Table A contains a master identifier A and the identifier for table B. When I run the query in PHPmyadmin I get the expected results: Identifier A and Identifier B (or NULL for Identifier B when there is no record in the table B) when run on the website the results either give me both identifiers if present in both tables or neither identifiers if only found in Table A.

Can anyone give me an idea why on the website I don't get Identifier A and then NULL for identifier B?

Query

```
"SELECT jobindex.*, jobrequest.*, somebody.Name 
FROM  jobindex
LEFT JOIN jobrequest ON jobindex.idJobIndex=jobrequest.idJobIndex  
JOIN somebody ON jobindex.idSomebody=somebody.idSomebody
WHERE jobindex.JobStatus NOT IN ('Closed', 'Removed') "
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning the data as an associative array (in PHP), dictionary (in Python), or hash (in Perl), you'll have a problem if two tables have columns with the same name. The key just contains the column name, without the table prefix, so you can't get the column from both tables. It will pick one of the tables to use, probably the last one in the `SELECT` clause.

You should give the columns aliases so that you can distinguish them:

```
SELECT jobindex.idJobIndex AS ji_id, jobrequest.idJobIndex AS jr_id, jobindex.*, jobrequest.*, somebody.Name
```

Now when there's no match, `$row['ji_id']` will contain the value from `jobindex`, `$row['jr_index']` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggested answer I changed the line

```
SELECT jobindex.*, jobrequest.*, somebody.Name
```

to a full select statement with each field explicitly stated

```
SELECT JI.idJobIndex,JI.idSomebody,JI.JobType, JI.JobReceivedStaff, JI.JobTitle, JI.JobStatus ..... JR.idJobRequest, JR.JobResponseStaff, somebody.Name 
FROM  jobindex as JI
```

This has corrected the issues I was having.